# Swift KVO binding not updated

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, datepicker, key-value-observing

In my macOS application, I want to combine a textual with a visual NSDatePicker. Therefore, I've made a custom NSDatePicker, which shows a popup when clicked.

[image: Textual and Visual NSDatePicker]

The textual picker is linked to a variable using the binding inspector:
[image: binding inspector of textual picker]

My problem is, while the textual picker is updated visually when selecting something in the popover, the bound value (prop_dateTime) isn't updated.

Some approaches i've tried:

```
class TextualAndVisualDatePickerElement: NSDatePicker {
    [...]
    func showPopover(sender: NSDatePicker) {
        //using Bond
        self.reactive.objectValue.bidirectionalBind(to: visualDatePicker.reactive.objectValue)

        //using KVO
        visualDatePicker.bind(.value, to: self, withKeyPath: "dateValue", options: [:])

        //using setValue
        _ = self.reactive.objectValue.observeNext(with: {self.setValue($0, forKey: "dateValue")})
        _ = visualDatePicker.reactive.objectValue.observeNext(with: {sender.setValue($0, forKey: "dateValue")})

        //using willChange
        _ = self.reactive.objectValue.observeNext(with: {visualDatePicker.willChangeValue(forKey: "dateValue"); visualDatePicker.dateValue = $0 as! Date; visualDatePicker.didChangeValue(forKey: "dateValue")})
        _ = visualDatePicker.reactive.objectValue.observeNext(with: {self.willChangeValue(forKey: "dateValue"); self.dateValue = $0 as! Date; self.didChangeValue(forKey: "dateValue")})

    }
    [...]
    //using keyPaths
    override public class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
        if key == "dateValue" {
            return Set(["visualDatePicker.dateValue"])
        }
        if key == "visualDatePicker.dateValue" {
            return Set(["dateValue"])
        }
        return Set([])
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @objc dynamic var objectControllerContent : ObjectControllerContent = ObjectControllerContent()

    @IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!
    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        label.stringValue = "prop_dateTime is \(objectControllerContent.prop_dateTime)"
    }
}

class ObjectControllerContent : NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var prop_dateTime : Date?
}
```

Result:
[image: Result]

github project: https://github.com/Florrr/VisualNSDatePicker

Comment: Which object is `self` in the code? What is `Object Controller`? How is `prop_dateTime` declared? How is the visual value of the textual date picker updated when you change the date picker in the popover?

Comment: `prop_dateTime` must be declared with `@objc dynamic` attribute. By the way, in the `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue` version you have to `return super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key)` rather than `Set[]`

Comment: I've updated the original post (hopefully, you understand the problem now better)

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue in a test project?

Comment: Please add the code where you set the value of the textual date picker.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "code where you set the value", as that is already included in my first post?
But I've uploaded a testproject to github, which includes the whole code.

Comment: I still don't understand which statements of "Some approaches I've tried" work and which don't, I'm not familiar with `reactive`. The binding of a control is not triggered by setting `objectValue`. See [Make NSTextField update its bound value when setting its string value programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173687/make-nstextfield-update-its-bound-value-when-setting-its-string-value-programmat).

Comment: @Willeke None of my approaches worked, as the binding wasn't triggered..
But thanks for the link - the swift solution there worked perfectly!
If you answer that to the question, i'll mark you answer as working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `dateValue` or `objectValue` of a `NSDatePicker` or any `NSControl` doesn't trigger the binding. The binding is triggered in `sendAction(_:to:)`.

Solutions:

call `sendAction(_:to:)`, the action and/or the target can be `nil`.

```
datePicker.dateValue = date
datePicker.sendAction(datePicker.action, to: datePicker.target)
```

or mimic the binding

```
datePicker.dateValue = date
guard
    let bindingInfo = datePicker.infoForBinding(NSBindingName.value),
    let observedObject = bindingInfo[NSBindingInfoKey.observedObject] as? NSObject,
    let observedKeyPath = bindingInfo[NSBindingInfoKey.observedKeyPath] as? String else {
        return
}
observedObject.setValue(self.dateValue, forKeyPath: observedKeyPath)
```